# Disable TreeGrid XML caching

Tags: java, gwt, caching, smartgwt

I am having a treegrid which has a XML datasource. Now even when the XML is changed and i refresh the page, the old tree is displayed and not the new one. I have also tried setting the datasource as `setPreventHTTPCaching(true);`.

Comment: Can you paste here some of your code?

Comment: check out this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466780/drag-drop-with-xml-based-datasource-not-working-in-smartgwt

Comment: the same code except that it does not change the XML. In my code the XML changes but it is not reflected in the code